# Where can I find the NTSB order for Administrator v. Walkup and/or v. Hamre?

Tags: faa-regulations, cfi, ntsb

In a footnote to [Administrator v Strobel](https://www.ntsb.gov/legal/alj/OnODocuments/Aviation/4384.PDF), the NTSB states:

> Our precedent makes clear that, “[r]egardless of who is manipulating
>   the controls of the aircraft during an instructional flight, or what
>   degree of proficiency the student has attained, **the flight
>   instructor is always deemed to be the pilot-in-command**.”
>   Administrator v. Hamre, 3 NTSB 28, 31 (1977). This principle was
>   reaffirmed in Administrator v. Walkup, 6 NTSB 36 (1988).

[THE PILOT IN COMMAND AND THE FARS: THE BUCK STOPS HERE (ALMOST ALWAYS)](http://law.und.edu/_files/docs/ndlr/pdf/issues/83/3/83ndlr817.pdf) has some other examples of determining who is PIC and also refers to Hamre.

I can’t find either one on the NTSB site or with a search. Does anyone have a copy or a link to Hamre or Walkup?

Comment: @mins It might be helpful if you explain (answer or comment) how you found the Hamre order, that looks like the main question.

Comment: @mins I found Hamre and Moeslein but can’t find Walkup with your link. If I try to go directly to the NTSB site that you are searching, I need a login ID and password. Is there somewhere on the site where you can get one?

Comment: @mins Another question. Hamre is referenced as 3 NTSB 28, 31 (1977) but the order number is EA-4232. How do you find the order number from the reference?

Comment: [Here is the opinion and order](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwk9usc79b2d2un/Admin_v_Hamre.doc?dl=0) from Hamre.

Comment: @JScarry here are some excerpts from Walkup, I'm looking for the entire case because I too am interested.  http://justhelicopters.com/Portals/5/NTForums_Attach/walkup%20decision.pdf

Comment: Docket SE-12774 (Administrator V. Ridpath, 1992) contains the following sentence: "The law judge concluded that although respondent's role as a
safety pilot when his student was operating under simulated
instrument conditions made him a crewmember for purposes of
section 91.17, the fact that respondent did not have a medical
certificate meant that he could not have acted as pilot-incommand
since the student was himself a certificated pilot."  The interpretation that a CFI did not need a medical (for certain operations) post dated some earlier court cases.  Who is PIC - not always clear.